# Is dependency property same as a CLR property which emits a PropertyChanged event as callback?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

The question is related to WPF Data Binding and MVVM pattern.

I am bit confused now distinguishing between the Dependency property defined in the XAML.cs file as well as a CLR property defined in the view model which is bound to some property of a component

For example say, I have a textbox in MyPage.xaml. So I created a dependency property to bind the textbox text property in the MyPage.xaml.cs maybe some String. The next time, I created a viewModel MyPageViewModel.cs which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and 
created a CLR property there(String), which emits an event PropertyChanged when it changes or the property is set with a new value. So are these both the same? Is there any difference?

> I have 3 questions
>
> 1. Is the Dependency Property same as CLR property which emits a PropertyChanged event when it changes?
> 2. Whether Dependency property is written in the view itself(MyPage.xaml.cs) or can it be included in the view
>      model(MyPageViewModel.cs)?
> 3. In MVVM pattern, we use the CLR properties more which emits an event during property change. So can dependency property be replaced
>      by such kind of CLR properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You usually don't use dependency properties in view models. They are instead used in view elements, where they can get their values from data bindings, styles, animations, etc.

Comment: Dependency properties also emits NotifyChanged event right? So is it the same as ViewModel properties?

Comment: Not exactly the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but a similar notification mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An dependency property is on a `DependencyObject` from which all WPF UI elements derive from (and only works there), as it's static and saves it's value in a kind of collection assigned to a specific `DependencyObject` (on which the dependency property is defined). Dependency properties can be defined in a class outside of the actual `DependencyObject` to extend it's functionality without modifying the original user control class.

When you write a user control and want a ViewModel to allow to bind a value and receive notifications when it's changed, then you create a dependency property.

Imagine it like an USB cable, where you have a male plug and a female receptacle. The CLR property is like the plug and the dependency property is like the receptacle.

A dependency property allows you to store that's associated with a control but isn't part of the instance. As you can see on the [MSDN Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),


...


    );
public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

the dependency property is static and `GetValue` and `SetValue` are methods of `DependencyObject` (base class on which all WPF UI elements are based on).

Depencency Properties (and attached properties/attached behavior) can also be used to extend the functionality of a `UserControl` without inheriting from the actual user control type, i.e. notifying the ViewModel when a certain value changes which is not provided by the original user control.

> 1. Is the Dependency Property same as CLR property which emits a PropertyChanged event when it changes?

No, it's not the same. They are both 2 sides of the databinding engine. A DP is defined on the view to allow a view model to bind a INPC Property (Property that rises `PropertyChanged` event)

> 2. Whether Dependency property is written in the view itself(MyPage.xaml.cs) or can it be included in the view model(MyPageViewModel.cs)?

DP are part of the View-Layer as they depend on `DependencyObject`, which is part of the WPF framework and hence view concern. While technically nothing prevents you from  using them in the ViewModel, this causes a tight coupling of your ViewModel towards a certain View technology, so it doesn't fully comply MVVM pattern.

Be aware though that unit testing Dependency Properties may be quite difficult as they **don't** store the values on the class they are defined on but in some kind of dictionary where the `GetValue`/`SetValue` methods warp around.

Last but not least, since `DependencyObject` is the base class of all UI it is as well as most of the classes that derive from it thread affine, which means you can only access it from the thread you created which may cause you much pain in both unit test (especially if the tests run in parallel like MSTest used to do. Dunno if its still true as of today) and in your code.

> 3. In MVVM pattern, we use the CLR properties more which emits an event during property change. So can dependency property be replaced by such kind of CLR properties?

In ViewModels you could and you should use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you are developing a user control, you shouldn't replace DPs with "CLR" properties, because this makes the property not work with databinding in XAML.

If your UI elements should expose a property which can be used with data binding you have to use dependency properties (or attached properties which are pretty similar, but you place attached properties on i.e. the child elements. `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` are examples of attached properties).

Comment: "registers to a user control (and only works there)" is incorrect. It can be registered and used on any type that derives from DependencyObject, which isn't necessarily a user control. Although considered bad practice, people may even derive their view model classes from DependencyObject, and use dependency properties there. Such a design is neither impossible nor explicitly forbidden.

Comment: Point taken. Was meant to say any UI element, so I edited to make it a bit more clear. All I can say for the second part: It's also not impossible to write your code in procedural way without OOP just with static methods or write an application only with static singletons, but seriously which sane developer does that?

Comment: But still I am confused. The 3 questions are not exactly answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.